# writing on new window - new lines are lost

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="cardtitle">WEB</div>
<textarea id="web">
abc
abc
abc
</textarea>

<div id="btnprint">PRINT</div>
```

JS

```
tosend = '';
$('#btnprint').click(function(){
    $('.cardtitle').each(function(){
        tosend = tosend + 
        $(this).text().toUpperCase() + '<br>' + 
        $(this).next().val() + 
        '<hr>'
    });
    w=window.open();
    w.document.write(tosend);
    w.print();
    w.close();
});
```

Result is `abc abc abc`
Instead of:
`abc
abc
abc`

New lines are lost.

Comment: You need to replace all the newlines in `$(this).text()` with `<br>`.

Comment: Or wrap `<pre>` `</pre>` around `tosend`.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a `<pre>` tag so that the formatting won't be lost.

```
$('#btnprint').click(function(){
    var tosend = '<pre>';
    $('.cardtitle').each(function(){
        tosend = tosend + 
        $(this).text().toUpperCase() + '<br>' + 
        $(this).next().val() + 
        '<hr>'
    });
    tosend += '</pre>';
    w=window.open();
    w.document.write(tosend);
    w.print();
    w.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

New line characters are not rendered as line breaks in HTML. You need to use the `<br>` tag in order to start a new line.

What you can do is to replace the new line characters with `<br>`s:

```
...
$(this).next().val().replace(/[\n]/g, "<br>")
...
```

Comment: only first new line is replaced !

Comment: @bonaca You are right. Edited my answer to replace all instances of new line characters.